# Equivalent of Preprocessor definitions for an external assembly - Change intellisense or give a compile time error based on a setting

Tags: c#

I have a database that I connect to using a library. Some of the tables haven't changed in years, like the `ErrorLog` table. Others, like `Inventory`, change occasionally and slightly. This has gone on for many years before my time. The consequence of this is, we now have a small mountain of assemblies depending on which exact version of the database you're using. This creates a maintenance nightmare of Customer X is on version 4.3.0.7 and we want them to use this utility but the utility is for version 4.4.1.3, even though the three tables the utility uses haven't changed at all.

I've been attempting to write a new and hopefully improved library for using the database, but it's hindered by the fact that, because of all the different customers on different database versions, the library is truly only compatible with the latest version. Even though, quite often, 90% of what I want to do exists in the new library and it would only be a few dozen lines of code to merge in the missing/deprecated functionality. I would love to be able to merge a lot of this into something more manageable. If it was all in the same project I could do something like..

```
#if Version4301
   #define ErrorLog
#endif
#if Version4413
   #define ErrorLog
#endif

#if ErrorLog
  //ErrorLog class is defined in here
#endif

#if Version4413
   //Definition for Inventory.Explode() is in here
#endif
```

And then in the caller

```
#define Version4301

ErrorLog.Log();

Inventory.Explode(); //This should be me a compiler error
```

But to my knowledge, since `#define` is a proprocessor directive, I can't use it on any already compiler external assemblies.

**Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:**

- I want to have a single assembly used for this database access, and I
  want it to be compatible with the many different versions of the
  database
- I want the user of the assembly to set something, be it a
  config/setting/#define/etc that lets them easily specify the version
  of the database they want to target
- If they try to use a property/field/class/method (feature/table/column) that doesn't exist in the
  version they're targeting, I don't want it to appear in intellisense,
  or at the **very least** I want a compiler error. Don't want to wait until runtime

Is there a way in C# that I can do what I want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Equivalent of Preprocessor definitions for an external assembly - Change intellisense or give a compile time error based on a setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25777025/equivalent-of-preprocessor-definitions-for-an-external-assembly-change-intelli)

To the best of my knowledge, what you want cannot be done using C#.

The C# Language Specification includes the following "conditional" functionality:

- Conditional compilation symbols
- Conditional compilation directives
- Conditional methods

If creating a single assembly is more important than the compiler error: Define an application setting. Have each version specific method check the value of the application setting and throw an exception if appropriate.

If the compiler error is more important than creating a single assembly: Use conditional compilation symbols and directives to include the version specific functionality. Create a script to compile the code once for each version specific compilation symbol. Provide each user with the appropriate version specific assembly.

Comment: It's hard to say. I really want to get away from the multiple assemblies because, like I said, we have a small mountain and they're a pain to maintain. The compiler warnings I want because I don't want programmers to use features that aren't available to the version they're using, but that they won't find out about until after compilation

Comment: If you compile all of the assemblies from the same source code that uses conditional compilation directives and script the compilation on a build server, it should require no additional effort on the behalf of the developers to create the "small mountain" of assemblies as opposed to a single assembly.